# Container is not running

Tags: docker, ubuntu

I am new to docker and installed it into Ubunut to run Vyos, I used 
https://hub.docker.com/r/2stacks/vyos/
to but when I run this:

```
sudo docker exec -it vyos /bin/vbash
```

I get this error

```
Error response from daemon: Container 3318bce13f3b883188ebbb02blAblABlA970d0287 is not running
```

Comment: `docker run -it --rm 2stacks/vyos /bin/vbash`

Comment: Can you please add the output of `docker ps -a`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run docker exec , it will try to launch your commands inside a running container.

In your case you can do both things (Create a container and Launch a command) together like

```
$ docker run --rm -it 2stacks/vyos /bin/vbash
```

Assuming you will not this container after your execution (--rm will remove that container after execution)